# api return empty json file after process

Tags: java, api, spring-boot, org.json

I have a spring API where I need to do a process on the json file i receive and return them to another url with the result of the process.

I have 2 problems here:

1/I need to read the JSONObject I receive because when I send a json file I reveive an empty json file.

2/I need to return a JSONObject. What I send is a json file which contain `{"empty":true}`.

First of all, the library org.json is imposed on me so I can't use any other library (well I was using org.json.simple and it worked for me but then they imoosed the org.json library). I tried to change the object I recieve to a String and do the process. It works but I prefer to receive a JSONObject.
By the way I looked in the internet and stackoverflow but I didn't find a solution.

Here is the main code

```java
@Service
public class DataService {

    @Value("${my.config.api.atos.user}")
    private String user;
    @Value("${my.config.api.atos.password}")
    private String password;
    @Value("${my.config.folder}")
    private String path;


    //It works with org.json.simple library.

    // I would prefer that the variable is a JSONObject
    public static String processData(String str) { 
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(str);
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
        Data data = new Data();

        try {
            data = mapper.readValue(jsonObject.toString(), Data.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        List<DataJson> timeserie = data.getData();
        List<Double> values = new ArrayList<Double>();
        DataJson inter;
        for (int i = 0; i<timeserie.size(); i++){
            inter = timeserie.get(i);
            values.add(inter.getValue());
        }
        System.out.println(values);
        int EmbeddingDimension;
        EmbeddingDimension = data.getEmbeddingDimension();
        data.setResult(DynamicProperties.PermEn(values, EmbeddingDimension));

        String url = "http://localhost:8080/crosscpp/toolbox/test";

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        RequestBody body = null;

        try {
            body = RequestBody.create(
                    MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8"), objectMapper.writeValueAsString(data));
            System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(data));
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .post(body)
                .build();
        Call call = client.newCall(request);

        try {
            Response response = call.execute(); 
            String result = response.body().string();
            System.out.println(result);
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
            System.out.println(json);
            return result;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here is the json object I send:

```json
{
    "inputAeonSubscriptionUrl": "xxxx",
    "outputAeonPublicationUrl": "xxxx",
    "EmbeddingDimension": 3,
    "offerId": "xxxxxx",
    "measurement-channel-id": "1",
    "id": "xxxxxx",
    "submissionDate": {
        "min": "2019-04-09",
        "max": "2019-05-07"
    },
    "travelDates": {
        "min": "2019-05-13",
        "max": "2019-05-17"
    },
    "travelledDuration": {
        "min": 1,
        "max": 2
    },
    "geoBoundingBox": {
        "latitude-max": 51.507561,
        "latitude-min": 51.497715,
        "longitude-min": 7.482349,
        "longitude-max": 7.500885
    },
    "data": [{
            "value": 1,
            "timestamp": "2019-04-09"
        },
        {
            "value": 3,
            "timestamp": "2019-04-09"
        },
        {
            "value": 2,
            "timestamp": "2019-04-09"
        },
        {
            "value": 1,
            "timestamp": "2019-04-09"
        },
        {
            "value": 2,
            "timestamp": "2019-04-10"
        },
        {
            "value": 3,
            "timestamp": "2019-04-10"
        },
        {
            "value": 2,
            "timestamp": "2019-04-10"
        }
    ]
}
```

here is DataController:

```java
@RestController
public class DataController {

    private final DataService dataservice;

    @Autowired
    public DataController(DataService dataservice) {
        this.dataservice = dataservice;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/test")
    public JSONObject getAllDataT(@RequestBody JSONObject data) {
        return data;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/testjson")
    public JSONObject getAllDataT2(@RequestBody JSONObject json) {
        return json;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/timeseries"/*, produces = "application/json"*/)
    public JSONObject proccessAtosData(@RequestBody String data) {
        return dataservice.processData(data);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/save")
    public void saveAtosData(@RequestBody JSONObject json) {
        dataservice.savefile(json);
    }
}
```

and finaly here is the data class :

```java
public class Data {

    private String inputAeonSubscriptionUrl;
    private String outputAeonPublicationUrl;
    private int embeddingDimension;
    private String offerId;
    private String measurement_channel_id;
    private String id;
    private SubDate submissionDate;
    private TravelDates travelDates;
    private TravelDuration travelledDuration;
    private GeoBoundingBox geoBoundingBox;
    private List<DataJson> data;
    private double result;
    //private String model;

    public Data(){
    }

    public Data(@JsonProperty("inputAeonSubscriptionUrl") String inputAeonSubscriptionUrl, @JsonProperty("outputAeonPublicationUrl") String outputAeonPublicationUrl,
                @JsonProperty("EmbeddingDimension") int embeddingDimension, @JsonProperty("offerId") String offerId,
                @JsonProperty("measurement-channel-id") String measurement_channel_id, @JsonProperty("id") String id,
                @JsonProperty("submissionDate") SubDate submissionDate, @JsonProperty("travelDates") TravelDates travelDates,
                @JsonProperty("travelledDuration") TravelDuration travelledDuration, @JsonProperty("geoBoundingBox") GeoBoundingBox geoBoundingBox,
                @JsonProperty("data") List<DataJson> data/*, String model*/) {
        this.inputAeonSubscriptionUrl = inputAeonSubscriptionUrl;
        this.outputAeonPublicationUrl = outputAeonPublicationUrl;
        this.embeddingDimension = embeddingDimension;
        this.offerId = offerId;
        this.measurement_channel_id = measurement_channel_id;
        this.id = id;
        this.submissionDate = submissionDate;
        this.travelDates = travelDates;
        this.travelledDuration = travelledDuration;
        this.geoBoundingBox = geoBoundingBox;
        this.data = data;
        //this.model = model;
    }

// getters amd setters

}
```

If you need any more information from me just tell me and I will try to post them.

Comment: add more codes please. How is processsData called.

Comment: @Samim I just added the others class

Comment: first of all "org.json" library was originally developed as a proof of concept for implementation of JSON in Java. The performance of that library is worst among all the libraries available today and so people don't use this library. An alternative for that will be Jackson library which is inbuilt in Spring Boot. Another thing i would point is the way you are using `@RequestBody`. This is a very cumbersome implementation that you were instructed to do.

Comment: See this tutorial on how things are done with Jackson https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-rest-api-tutorial-with-mysql-jpa-hibernate/

Comment: also to create POJO classes you can use the following site. Just paste the JSON on their textbox click generate and you get your POJO. this will dramatically reduce your coding time. here you go http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: @Samim Thank you man about all the informations. I know that "org.json" is one of the least used library but as I said it is imposed on me. If it was up to me I would not use it. I just want to know if you think there will be a problem if I changed the json file from "org.json" to "org.json.simple" by passing by a String or not.